# How many questions with recent activity are visible in the summary popup of the Stack Exchange bar?

Tags: support, design, achievements-dialog

I don't know what the bar at the top is called, so I will go with the Stack Exchange bar.

So right next to the name we see a popup showing a brief summary. Inside there's a section where the question/answers that have *recently* received votes are mentioned. I have never known how many question (maximum) are visible and how long does this stay.

What I have achieved is a maximum of four questions and don't have any idea on how long they remain active in the summary popup.

Comment: Could you try rephrase your question.  Its hard to understand exactly what is being asked here...

Comment: is it better now?

Comment: Not really... there is still no question mark :P hehe... in anycase - there can be quite a few... [I count 7](http://i.imgur.com/ANlOk.png)

Comment: @Lix I think 7 is the limit, but official response from a dev or someone who can find blog or post about it will be cool. :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this question refer to an earlier incarnation of the achievement inbox.

[image]

The number of items shown there is 50 (I checked this both in my main account and in a sockpuppet account.)

Comment: Shouldnt we then close as no longer reproducable?

Comment: Perhaps ... I only posted this answer since I couldn't find this information anywhere else...